# Combining multiple Case statements into single output column

Tags: sql, case

I need to re-categorise a column `marketing_channel` with 10 unique values into 15 distinct groups by matching certain criteria.
I've done this via case statements but then the output is in 15 new columns.

1. Is there a more elegant way to re-class the marketing_channel by simply adding 1 extra column like `"marketing_sub_channel"` that contains all new 15 classes?
2. Is there  better way to do the classification than by creating 15 case statements? Was thinking a `with` clause, but that would also be quite lengthy

[image]

Output looks like this but ultimately just a single added column would be great:
[image]

Comment: case _expressions_, not statements. (Values are returned.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you just have to change the format a bit. Remove the "case" statement at the beginning of each line and just put the "End" at the end of the statement, like so :

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE null
END as marketing_sub_channel
```

or in your case:

```
CASE
    WHEN medium like ('%affiliate%') or marketing_cannel ='Affiliates' then 'Affiliate'
    WHEN campaign like ('%_Display brand_global Progromatic Display%') then 'Dispay' 
    WHEN campaign like ('%display%') and campaign not like ('progrommatic') then 'Dispay'
    ....
    else null
END as marketing_sub_channel
```

Also I would like to note that in your case statement since you have '%display%' and '%_Display brand_global Progromatic Display%' that you place the longer more specific one on top so it can trigger if it needs to. If '%display%' is on top then it will always trigger first since it contains a substring of the other one.